# How to verify a correct wp-cli installation?

Tags: wp-cli

I've installed wp-cli (or so I think) on my VPS, Centos 6.9.

when I'm logged in as my user, wp is found; but when I run `wp --info`
 from my home directory; I receive:

```
PHP binary: /usr/local/bin/php
PHP version:    5.6.30
php.ini used:   /usr/local/lib/php.ini
WP-CLI root dir:    phar://wp-cli.phar
WP-CLI vendor dir:  phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor
WP_CLI phar path:   /home/myusername
WP-CLI packages dir:    
WP-CLI global config:   
WP-CLI project config:  
WP-CLI version: 1.2.1
```

However, [WP-CLI project documentation](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/commit/e9bab3fae735604758fcb54b626620d790376cae) and on [wordpress.org](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/installing/) say that immediately after a successful 
isntall, your WP-CLI root and package directories should not be empty, like as follows:

```
PHP binary:    /usr/bin/php5
PHP version:    5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
php.ini used:   /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
WP-CLI root dir:        /home/wp-cli/.wp-cli
WP-CLI packages dir:    /home/wp-cli/.wp-cli/packages/
WP-CLI global config:   /home/wp-cli/.wp-cli/config.yml
WP-CLI project config:
WP-CLI version: 0.23.0
```

Is the documentation just that outdated or did I not install wp-cli correctly? 
Does my wp not have proper permissions to create directories (.wp-cli) in my home folder?

Comment: This looks like a regular installation. Just `cd` into a WordPress directory and try out the commands. If they work, you installed it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a functioning installation, I've learned. 
The [package directory](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/tools/) and global and project configs are blank by default during installation.